# Не включается short_open_tag в php_fpm

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Настраиваю веб-сервер под nginx, но не включается short_open_tag в php_fpm. Вот некоторые данные из phpinfo().

- System  Linux amorphine-desktop 4.2.0-38-generic #45~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 09:27:51 UTC 2016 x86_64
- Server API   FPM/FastCGI
- Virtual Directory Support    disabled
- Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /etc/php5/fpm
- Loaded Configuration File    /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
- Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d
- Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

---

- PHP Version  5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

---

- short_open_tag   Off

В /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini Задано явно:

```
    short_open_tag = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Сервис php5-fpm перезапускал. Директивы php_admin_value в pool.d закомменчены.

Comment: Посмотрите нет ли в pool.d/*.conf директив php_admin_value, которые перезаписывают значение short_open_tag

Comment: @cheops Нет, все директивы закомменчены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех php.ini оказалось по две директивы short_open_tag
Примечательно, что эти конфиги - дефолтные,и почему директив несколько - неясно. Здесь уже исправлена проблема по вопросу. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]